# Find the area with integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, measure-theory

I need to calculate the area of the following surface $A\subset \Bbb R^2$ using Fubini’s Theorem:
$$A := \left\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 ~:~ 1\le xy\le 2 \text{ and } 1 \le \frac yx \le 2\right\}$$
Can I first rewrite them as $\frac1 y ≤ x$, $\frac2 y ≤ x$ and $ x ≤ y, y≤ 2x$
Im not really sure how to go on from here so if anyone could help it would be wondeful

Comment: The boundaries of the region suggest substituting $u=xy$ and $v=\frac yx$, so the integral in the $(u,v)$ plane is taken over a rectangle.

Comment: Fubini's theorem we say that under some conditions we can change of order of integration, like as $\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}fdxdy=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}fdydx$. If the limits the integration they are not constants, we still we can apply the same idea but it is usually a little more complicated.  However the change of variables theorem says that we can change of region of integration, likes as $\iint_{R}fdA=\iint_{R^*}f|J|dA^*$, again under some conditions. The second one idea, seems exterminate the problem as you suggest user170231. For clarify: are you sure that you need Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @A.P. If you are asking me then that is what is asked of me to do. But would it be correct with user170231 idea if I just added up $\int^2_1 u du +\int^2_1 vdv$

Comment: @A.P. or would it be  u dxdy+v dxdy

Comment: what if we don't use the theorem would any of my previous comments be correct

Comment: Please avoid asking questions in the comments. All questions must be asked in your post. This is part of your effort that you must show. In your post you must indicate all your questions and your effort to solve it (see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) . As a last indication, you need to calculate the Jacobian of the change of variable. @ugjumb

Comment: I used it and got 4,5 x^2\y^2 which is not very helpful

Comment: and plus if you would have been more helpful I wouldn't have to ask a million questions in the comments :)

Comment: @ugjumb so if I understood correctly, basically you have to calculate the area of $A$?

Comment: @SineoftheTime Yap

Comment: @ugjumb then just perform a change of coordinates and compute the determinant of the Jacobian